# UISegmentedControl setTitle:forSegmentAtIndex:, explicit dispatch to main thread needed?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa-touch

I have a notification which can be posted on a background thread. This notification eventually leads to calling `setTitle:forSegmentAtIndex:`, which is UISegmentedControl, part of the UIKit.

Should it be assumed that I need to wrap this `setTitle:forSegmentAtIndex:` call with a async call to main thread, or will some lower lying Cocoa code automatically dispatch anything like `setTitle:forSegmentAtIndex:` to the main thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always dispatch code that modifies a UI control to the main queue. Always.